# Is there a place to search several/all Stack Exchange sites at once?

Tags: support

Despite using Google more than any other "tool" at work and in life... I still can't seem to search for what I want/need sometimes. I tried to search for the answer of my question on Meta; nothing too useful returned. When I typed my title to this question, more relevant results were returned below the title box, but it is still not what I want (why can the title box always search better than I can?). Anyway... sorry if this is posted somewhere.

Is there a way I can search several or all Stack Exchange sites at once? Sometimes I have a question that could be answered several places. Examples off the top of my head...

- Password hashing: *Stack Overflow*, *Code Review*, *Information Security*, maybe *Programmers* (conceptual and code could each individually answer things, because I can easily apply practice and concept in my own code, or just seeing working code is nice).
- MySQL issues (beyond queries): *Stack Overflow*, *Database Administrators*, maybe *Unix & Linux*
- Troubleshooting HTTP request issues: *Stack Overflow*, *Unix & Linux*, maybe *Webmasters* or *Information Security*...

Note: this is not a feature request if it doesn't exist; I am just wondering. I'm not sure if Google will let me search specific sites or not (I know I can do one specific site), but Google really destroys necessary punctuation sometimes. Also, for certain things, I honestly want to look for an answer on Stack Exchange sites before I want to deal with other sites that would be returned by google.

I don't always initially know which ones would be most helpful to me. Sometimes I am really surprised at which Stack Exchange site I find my answer or if I find a link to an answer on a different Stack Exchange site from an Stack Overflow answer. Sometimes I discover new beta sites this way, too. I just want to search all technology, I think... And `site:stackexchange.com` on Google doesn't seem to work for Stack Overflow because `stackoverflow.stackexchange.com` isn't Stack Overflow.

Comment: More important: Searching [MSO] & [MSE] at the same time…

Comment: `stackoverflow.stackexchange.com` is nonexistent.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the [main Stack Exchange page](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=password%20hashing) search field, it's Google powered and gives results on all sites of the network. Noting that it doesn't search within comments. I tried a very specific keyword, that's first result on Google `keyword site:stackexchange.com`, but it doesn't show up in the custom SE search.

<kbd>![password hashing][2]</kbd> 
  
<kbd>![m is m][3]</kbd>

Comment: totally didn't read the words in that search box... I thought it was searching _for_ SE sites, not _on_ SE sites.  [Awesome.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/)

Comment: Another [example](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=salt).

Comment: Or if you want to be adventurous you could use the Data Explorer.

Comment: The only way to search comments is to use SEDE; I whipped up [this quick query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/218092/search-comments) a while ago and it seems to do the trick.

Comment: @AstroCB, well, I use to find them with Google. I wrote a spanish word in a comment at SOpt Meta and it's indeed the [only result](https://www.google.com/search?q=servilleta+site%3Ameta.pt.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I find it ironic how the first comment on the question states "google.com" as a joke but right under that seach box in the image it says "powered by google.com". Not so much of a joke afterall :P

Comment: Note: I don't think the stackexchange.com search is Google-powered anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer pointed out, [the main StackExchange page search field](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=keyword) *gives different results and does not search comments*.

**Therefore**  [I use google directly (click me)](https://www.google.de/search?q=keyword+site:stackexchange.com+OR+site:askubuntu.com+OR+site:mathoverflow.net+OR+site:serverfault.com+OR+site:stackoverflow.com+OR+site:stackapps.com+OR+site:superuser.com) **utilizing the OR-Operator to search on all sites**.

*Note:* This search takes into account all sites ([see site domains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81383/356641) - and will also include new sites, because [new sites are subdomains of stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248455/356641)). Very comfortable using a browser custom search, [e.g. in firefox](https://superuser.com/a/7374/598004). Happy searching :).

Answer (score -2):

There is a 09/01/2022 SEDE query on meta Stack Exchange [Cross Stack Exchange search through all of my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360602/787861) of the user [Glorfindel](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/18973) which I ran a few times and got what I wanted, takes about a minute and sometimes times out, but it works.